# Access 16 append query - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am still not too experienced with access, SQL, VBA and this is my first post. So please go easy on me! Okay lets get to it. I have been updating an access file due to irrelevant and duplicate records showing up on reports.

First I was having trouble appending records due to Key violations that I determined was due to appending to primary key fields, which I remedied by creating an autonumber ID Primary key on the destination table. I am having trouble updating the query with a WHERE clause to not add records already on the destination table. Field and table names have been changed below, but I am trying to insert into "dandy" from "bag" and "rug".

Error message reads:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '"NOOB"
        WHERE [rug].[TENT] AND [rug].[CANDY] NOT IN (SELECT [TENT] AND [CANDY] FROM [dandy])'.
```

See SQL Code below:

```
INSERT INTO dandy(CANDY, FUN, DOG, TREAT, BUMPY, TENT, System )
    SELECT  Val([CANDY]) AS Burger,
            Val([FUN]) AS FUN_VAL,
            rug.STOVE,
            rug.TREAT,
            IIf([Bag]![Water] Is Not Null,[Bag]![Water],[rug]![BUMPY]) AS BUMPY,
            rug.TENT,
            "NOOB" AS System
    FROM rug 
        INNER JOIN [crib] ON rug.CANDY= [crib].Dip)
        INNER JOIN Bag ON ([crib].FacNum = Bag.[Trip]) AND (rug.TENT = Bag.Lip)
    GROUP BY 
        Val([CANDY]),
        Val([FUN]),
        [rug].STOVE,
        [rug].TREAT,
        IIf([Bag]![Water] Is Not Null,
        [Bag]![Water]
        [rug]![BUMPY]),
        rug.TENT,
        "NOOB"
    WHERE [rug].[TENT] AND [rug].[CANDY] NOT IN (SELECT [TENT] AND [CANDY] FROM [dandy])
    HAVING  (((IIf([Bag]![Water] Is Not Null,
               [Bag]![Water],
               [rug]![BUMPY])) Is Null));
```

Comment: I think your `WHERE` statement needs to be split up.  The `AND` cannot be where it is at.  It should read `WHERE [rug].[TENT] NOT IN (SELECT [TENT] AND [CANDY] FROM [dandy]) AND [rug].[CANDY] NOT IN (SELECT [TENT] AND [CANDY] FROM [dandy])`

Comment: Thanks Zak, let me give that a whirl. when you split up the `WHERE` should the `NOT IN SELECT` be split up too? I see `NOT IN (SELECT [TENT] AND [CANDY]` following `WHERE [rug].[TENT]`

Comment: Honestly I don't know about MSACCESS, but in other queries it's fine as it sits .. You can have multiples in the SELECT.

Comment: Thank you Zak. I am still getting a syntax error at the same point. but I was unaware of those limits on the where clause.

Comment: Why are you grouping? Try a simple query to test. `SELECT Tent, Candy, "Noob" AS System FROM rug GROUP BY Tent, Candy, "Noob"` - what happens why you try to view datasheet? In query design set the "Noob" field as an EXPRESSION, not GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent duplicate pairs of Tent and Candy in table, just set a compound Index in table with those two fields. Records that would cause duplication will be rejected. The IN() criteria can be eliminated.

As for the IN() criteria, I tested your original syntax. It does not error but also does not retrieve records.  Splitting into two NOT IN() expressions also failed - no records met the `AND` condition.

```
WHERE TENT NOT IN (SELECT TENT FROM dandy) AND CANDY NOT IN (SELECT CANDY FROM dandy)
```

However, concatenation did retrieve correct records.

```
SELECT * FROM datasource        
WHERE TENT & CANDY NOT IN (SELECT TENT & CANDY FROM dandy)
```

Comment: Thank you June7. I am still getting syntax error at the same point (either at `"NOOB"` or at `WHERE`). I thought to just change the append query to a select query and build a new append query with your concatenated `WHERE` clause using the new select query. First, what do you think of that quick solution? Second, in my new append query when I run it prompts me with "Enter Parameter Value" window for `Candy`. I am going to do some web research about what is causing the window but figured I'd update you on it. Thanks again!

Comment: If you get a popup prompt on `Candy`, it is because Access cannot find anything with that name. My recommendation is still to set the compound index and get rid of the IN() criteria.

Comment: I created a unique index using fields `Candy` and `Tent`, that was a much simpler solution. And regarding the popup prompt, you are right that was because I forgot to update a table name in a calculated field. But now I don't need the `WHERE NOT IN` statement thanks to the unique compound index. And I saw yourcomment above about changing system to an expression. Thank you, that is actually in design view as an expression but was still being included. I updated that too.

Comment: I have one unresolved concern that pre-existed my updates to this file. as mentioned at the start I am trying to insert into `dandy` from `bag` and `rug`. One field involved in the unique compound index, `Tent`, is coded differently in each source table. `bag` places leading zeros on the string to make it 8 characters but `rug` does not have leading zeros, causing dupes. Table `bag` is a linked table, in it the field size is 255 and data type of short text. Table `rug` is an ODBC database, in it the field size is 8 and data type is also short text. Should I start a new question for this? thx!

Comment: Convert the source fields into whatever data type and structure needed for the destination table. You are already doing that with some fields using Val() function. Why would it be any different for Tent? Do you want to be able to join dandy back to rug and bag tables?

Comment: `bag` is a linked excel table. I can update that table but not `rug`. No I am not trying to join `dandy` back into them. Honestly, the reason it is different for `tent` is because State systems can be poorly executed at times. Two systems hold incomplete parts of the same data, and where they house the same data for some reason design of the new system used to create `bag` puts leading zeros in front. And some values have a letter in front indicating a different variety of the same data, even though there's another field on that table with that same letter indicating that same thing.

Comment: If tent is a text field in dandy it will take any of those structures. So would bag.tent and bag.candy duplicate rug.tent and rug.candy - in spite of the structural differences would they be the same entity? You need to decide if you should reconfigure the bag and rug values to meet the unique index condition.

Comment: By 'reconfigure' I mean calculate, not change the original data. Use string manipulation to modify the data in the INSERT action. If you need help with that, start a new question. Issue presented in this question has been addressed.